# Set TextBox Text in a User Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls

on my aspx page I have a div

```
<div id="MatterRiskControl" runat="server" />
```

in my code behind the aspx page I log in the relevant controls like this

```
uc = CType(Page.LoadControl("MatterRisk_Probate.ascx"), UserControl)
MatterRiskControl.Controls.Add(uc)
```

This works great although I have a textbox I want to set the text for in the code behind. In my ascx page the Text box is set like this

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" />
```

In the page load code behind the ascx page I have tried this

```
MyTextBox.Text = "Some Text Here"
```

But it doesn't set it.

And I am unsure how to reference the TextBox from the aspx code behind?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You need to provide a public property in your UserControl that gets/sets `MyTextBox.Text`. Then you can access it from your page in this way: `uc.MyTextBoxText = "foo"`. Of course you could get/set the whole `TextBox`, but it's better to provide only what is necessary, so the text.

Comment: Thanks! So I have set a public property in the UserControl, but in the code behind the aspx page it says 'textForTextBox' is not a member of 'UserControl'

Comment: Then don't cast your user-control to `UserControl`, which is the base type, but to the actualy type, like `MatterRisk_Probate`(if that's the name of the class).

Comment: Sorry for the simple questions, I havent got my head round it yet. So in my aspx code behind I have  Dim uc As UserControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("MatterRisk_Probate.ascx"), UserControl)

Comment: In my MatterRisk_Probate.ascx.vb I have at the top Partial Class FORM_MatterRisk_Probate

Comment: When I try Dim uc As UserControl = CType(Page.LoadControl("MatterRisk_Probate.ascx"), MatterRisk_Probate) it says MatterRisk_Probate is not defined

Comment: removing the CType still loads the controls so does it help to remove that? Dim uc As UserControl = Page.LoadControl("MatterRisk_Probate.ascx")

Comment: Have you considered putting the user control on the page and using its `Visible` property to set if it shown? That way you don't have to do anything convoluted to load it and access its controls.

Comment: See my several examples  below, I show some easy code on how you can approach the issue of wanting to change control values on the UC, but from code behind on the page that the UC was dropped into.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume a UC with a boatload of controls (text boxes, check boxes), all kind of fun stuff.

Short version:

Make public methods of the UC to change the text boxes you want.

There are many reasons for this, but the main reason for this is that you want a design that supports multiple instances of controls.

So, expose public methods.

Say this UC to edit a hotel.

```
        <h3>UC testing page</h3>

        Enter ID to show: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtHotelID" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" Text="Show Hotel"
            CssClass="btn"
            OnClick="cmdShow_Click"
            />
        <br />
        <br />

        <uc1:MyEditHotelC runat="server" 
            ID="MyEditHotelC" />
        <br />

        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <hr />
        <h3>This page button(s)</h3>
        Enter new hotel text: 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtMyHotel" runat="server">
        </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="cmdChangeHotel" runat="server" Text="Change HotelName"
            OnClick="cmdChangeHotel_Click"
            />
    </div>
```

So, note the UC.

So, we have this:

[image]

So, in the UC, we do this:

```
Public Sub ChangeHotel(strText As String)

    Me.txtHotel.Text = strText

End Sub
```

Note in above, we can use the SAME control name for the text box on the form behind, but that txtBox control WILL be changed by the UC when rendered.

So, code in the current page:

```
Protected Sub cmdChangeHotel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    MyEditHotelC.ChangeHotel(txtMyHotel.Text)

End Sub
```

So, note how we made/use/enjoy a public method of the UC, and thus on the current page we can with easy grab/get/change the text box control.

and you could well make a getter/setter if you need to read/use the text box value.

So, above could become this:

```
Public Property tHotel
    Get
        Return txtHotel.Text
    End Get

    Set(value)
        txtHotel.Text = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Once again, since 2 or 5 copies of the control could exist on the page, then which copy of the text box are you changing here?

So, I could update/change the hotelname of 2 UC's on the page like this:

```
        <uc1:MyEditHotelC runat="server" 
            ID="MyEditHotelC" />
        <br />

        <uc1:MyEditHotelC runat="server" 
            ID="MyEditHotelC2" />
        <br />
```

So, now code to change hotel on both would be this:

```
Protected Sub cmdChangeHotel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    MyEditHotelC.tHotel = txtMyHotel.Text
    MyEditHotelC2.tHotel = txtMyHotel.Text

End Sub
```

So, if you just need to get the values, then make a public function in your UC code behind.

However, if you need get and set of that text box, then expose a public Property as per above, and then you can change the text.

Even more amazing, is these values are THEN valid in markup:

Eg this:

```
        <uc1:MyEditHotelC runat="server" 
            ID="MyEditHotelC2"
            tHotel ="ABC"
            />
```

So, just like a Gridview with one text box? Well, which instance of the text box are you dealing with when you have 10 rows?

Same goes for a UC. If you have 5 on the page, which text box you going to get, grab, and then change?

So, the only real way to keep separate the multiple instances of the Text hotel box is to public expose getter and setters for each of those controls.

Now, you CAN of course in client side JavaScript still get the control, and change it, but for now, this post is a bit long, and the above should help with some great examples of an approach that I find works rather well.